# How to send local files to JMS queues using FTP sampler in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

How to send local files to JMS queues using FTP sampler in JMeter?
I'm using JMeter to implement but I'm not be able to figure out, how FTP and HTTP sampler send a file?

Comment: Could you add some things that you already tried? So that those options can already be ruled out.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) function is what you are looking for, just put it inside your JMS payload and provide path to the file like:

```
${__FileToString(/path/to/your/file.xml,,)}
```

See [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) posts series for more information on this and other JMeter Functions.

---

You won't be able to use [FTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#FTP_Request) or [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers for sending files to the Message Queues, they are totally different beasts and none of them is suitable for JMS connectivity.